# Am I too old? Is it too late? Starting, Resuming, or Mastering an instrument

Tags: learning, self-learning, beginner

*Age is a commonly expressed concern in studying music, and there are many questions on this site addressing "late starts" from a variety of perspectives. This post is intended as Link Central for users with related or similar questions.*

---

If you've found this question, chances are you're interested in learning to play an instrument or in some other aspect of music, like theory. But you are -- or feel you are -- getting a late start, and you have doubts: Is it even worth starting? How far can I go? You are far from alone, both in asking and in asking here. This post will help lead you to similar and related questions that have already been fielded by the community.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can one be too old to learn an instrument?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/76066/can-one-be-too-old-to-learn-an-instrument)

Comment: As long as you haven‘t to start a concert or solo  career in mind ... it will never be to late!

Comment: @BrianTowers - that's the first question quoted in the answer.

Comment: Wasn't the whole point of this question to cover any/all of the potential duplicates?  And put them all under one banner?

Comment: @Tim Indeed. There is a certain irony. :-)

Comment: @BrianTowers The answer you linked to is related, but is a different question. The intent here is to compile links to all the various age-related questions to make them easier to find, rather than to answer the question itself.

Comment: @Aaron was it your intention for this to be closed? Or are people misunderstanding the intent?

Comment: @topoReinstateMonica Appreciate your checking. I was not intending for it to be closed. Short of knowing why individual close votes were cast, I certainly allow for misunderstanding.

Comment: @Aaron maybe a post on meta clarifying your intent might be useful, if there isn't one already? I can see why a mod might want to lock such a post, but at the moment the single "This question already has answers here" link undermines the answer.

Comment: @topoReinstateMonica Agreed about Meta. My current thinking is to see what happens over the next day or so. One advantage to being closed vs. locked is that the answer can be edited to add new links as they appear.

Comment: I support the intention of Aaron. My first thought was: oh, he might be applying for moderator. I would also support this intentions. ;)

Comment: I vote to reopen this question. It is unfair to close it and nitpicking to say it is a duplicate. It is quite clear that this isn‘t a problem of Aaron and the intention is very serious.

Comment: I'd be for moving this to the meta, but it's not really a fit for the main site as is. It's mostly just pointing to other answers around the site which is not the point of a canonical question.  You should be able to point to a canonical question to get the answer, not have the canonical question point elsewhere. IMO, almost all questions in your answer should be closed as a duplicate of the question this is closed a duplicate of. I'm happy to talk about this more in chat if needed.

Comment: Perhaps one approach could be to make a meta post (or posts) listing 'good answers to common questions', so that when we do get common questions we don't have to search for them anew every time. A slightly trimmed-down version of Aaron's answer here (listing the best 'am i too old' questions) could be a part of that?

Comment: @Dom I see your points. Let me start by seeing if I can turn this into a better canonical question. Give me a few days.

Comment: @topoReinstateMonica I could definitely get behind this. Please consider adding it as an answer to the current meta discussion on canonical questions: [Should we create a FAQ about Music Theory?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/should-we-create-a-faq-about-music-theory)

Comment: Can this be made into a community wiki? I don't have a problem with rerunning a question if it would be beneficial to collect answers in one place, but I don't see why this OP should get the reputation for it.

Comment: @Max The option of a community wiki has been discussed. I (the OP) am not opposed, but have asked to wait to see if I can better adapt the question to fit as a canonical question. If we do go the community wiki route, it would probably also get moved to Meta, which I would also support. (For the time being, as the OP has done all of the work, the OP would like to receive the credit. However, should the question get re-opened, which is my goal, you could certainly add your own answer[s] and receive any reputation gain for it/them. For now, I'm just keeping the list of links up to date.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### The consensus here on SE MP&T is...

## Go for it!

Among the various questions and answers linked here, you'll find a wide variety of viewpoints: encouragement, pitfalls, concerns, and so forth, but in general, you will find that the broad feeling across the site is **"Yes, you can. Go for it."**

`NOTE: It's not always obvious from the title, but age is expressed as a concern in all of the listed questions.`

---

What follows is a list of questions regarding beginning to learn when you feel your age is a concern. They are organized by subject matter; just know that an answer related to an area different from yours might still be the one you're looking for.

#### Late start as a general concern

- [Can one be too old to learn an instrument?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/76066/70803)

#### Guitar

- [Is it ever too late to learn guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24827/70803)
- [Can one be too old to learn an instrument?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/76066/70803)
- [Methodology to Master Guitar as an adult](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/30400/70803)
- [Muscle Memory and Age](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/42220/70803)
- [How realistic is it to become a professional musician when you start learning music late at life?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/121993/70803)

#### Piano/Keyboard

- [Is It too late to start learning keyboard again?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12441/70803)
- [Is it too late for me to become good at piano?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/105089/70803)
- [What to choose? Violin or piano?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33828/70803)
- [Adult learning to play popular songs on piano](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15166/70803)
- [Learning piano in mid 30s](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/67492/70803)
- [Self-learning how to play the piano](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43824/70803)
- [Is it possible for me to learn piano very very good if I start at this age (26) ? If yes, how long would it take?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64622/70803)
- [Learning piano by autodidact after getting older](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17399/70803)
- [Jazz piano versus classical piano](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/570/70803)
- [What instrument can an old guy learn if the main goal is to write music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9649/70803)
- [Becoming proficient at piano at age 30?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/38815/70803)
- [ABRSM exams for adult beginners](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/45079/70803)
- [Is it too late to develop foundational piano techniques?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/129719/70803)

#### Saxophone

- [I want to learn the sax. Where should I start?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/13907/70803)

#### Violin

- [What to choose? Violin or piano?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33828/70803)
- [Restarting to play violin](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/91936/70803)
- [Learning my first instrument](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/42386/70803)
- [What is the right age to start learning to play violin?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/96/70803)
- [Can I learn violin without a teacher?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43036/70803)
- [What instrument can an old guy learn if the main goal is to write music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9649/70803)

#### Viola

- [Learning my first instrument](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/42386/70803)

#### Voice/Singing

- [Can one be too old to learn how to sing?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/104203/70803)
- [How can I improve my voice?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/74547/70803)
- [How to improve singing?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/23000/70803)
- [Should I stop practice singing and switch to fingerstyle guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/61158/70803)

#### Theory

- [Is it too late to learn music theory and composition?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32248/70803)

#### Composing

- [Is it too late to learn music theory and composition?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32248/70803)
- [What instrument can an old guy learn if the main goal is to write music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9649/70803)

#### Music school

- [Restarting to play violin](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/91936/70803)
- [Pianist at 22 years old](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/23644/70803)

#### Developing muscle memory

- [Muscle Memory and Age](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/42220/70803)

#### Exams / Auditions

- [ABRSM exams for adult beginners](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/45079/70803)

#### Going pro

- [How realistic is it to become a professional musician when you start learning music late at life?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/121993/70803)